# Facebook sharer not sharing if user session is not alive

Tags: session, facebook-sharer

I am using facebook sharer in our application. But in my implementation if the user is not logged already(facebook session is not alive) then it is being redirected to facebook login page. After login, the home page is being displayed but not the sharing confirmation page to proceed sharing. If the user session is active it is showing share screen so that user can share the page. To make this work fine when user Facebook session is not alive, do I need to add any parameter or something?

My code will look like :

`<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL&t=TITLE">Share this</a>`

Thanks
Sreeni.